# Landscape Background Images Are Offset In iOS 8

Tags: image, ios6, background, landscape, ios6.1

I've been updating some old iOS apps to iOS8 and have a problem with landscape apps.

The launch image is fine, but other background images are skewed (as if iOS 8 thinks the app is portrait).

In fact, ads - such as those from Chartboost - appear as if the app is also in portrait.

I am not using a storyboard.

I discovered this problem when a few of our landscape apps were rejected (I didn't have an iPhone 6 yet...now I do and now I see the problem).

Has anyone seen this problem? I would appreciate some guidance.

Thanks!